# Execute some code before performing the action in a form

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a global variable called `authorized`  which is set to `false` initially. It should then be set to `true` in the function called `isAuth(..)` This works as it should.

But initially the user is presented with the `form` where he should type in username, password, and a pin, as you can see in the `form` (where it says `if(req.url == "/")`). The `form` then has an action that calls `TwoFA`. The problem is with this. I make this check `if((req.url == "/TwoFA" && !authorized) {` and at this time the `authorized` should be set to `true`, cus it is set in the `isAuth(...)` function. When the user presses the submit button, it changes the url to "`/TwoFA`", and first after that it changes the `authorized` variable to true.

How can I go about this? I want it run check the `isAuth(...)` before it executes the `/TwoFA` function.
Here is my code

```
var authorized = false;

function isAuth(name, pass, pin) {
    if(name === nameOK && pass === passOK && pin === pinOK) {
        authorized = true;
        return true;
    } else {        
        return false;
    }
}

var server = http.createServer(function(req, resp) {
if(req.method == "POST") {
        collectRequestData(req, result => { 
            let uName = result.uName;
            let pwd = result.pwd;
            let pin = result.pin;
            let tlf = result.tlf;

            if(isAuth(uName, pwd, pin)) {                           
                sendMail(token);                            
            } else {
                print("Wrong credentials");
                return;
            }
        });

   if(req.url == "/") {
        resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html'});                        
        
        var html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>"+
                        "<head>"+                           
                            "<title>Webproj</title>"+                                                                               
                        "</head>"+
                        "<body>" +
                            "<div id='cDiv'>"+
                                "<h2> Welcome.</h2>"+
                                "<form action='TwoFA' method='post'>"+
                                    "<p>Username <input type='text' id='uName' name='uName' /></p>"+
                                    "<p>Password<input type='password' id='pwd' name='pwd' /></p>"+
                                    "<p>Pin code<input type='password' pattern='[0-9]*' inputmode='numeric' id='pin' name='pin' /></p>"+
                                    "<p>Your phone number (for the token)</p><p><input type='number' id='tlf' name='tlf' /></p>"+
                                    "<p><input type='submit' value='Login'>"+
                                "</form>"+
                            "</div>"+
                        "</body>"+                  
                    "</html>";
    
        resp.write(html);
        
        return;    
    }
    
    if((req.url == "/TwoFA" && !authorized) {
        resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        resp.write('<html><body><p>You are not authorized to see this page</p></html>');
        
        return;
    } 
});

function TwoFA(user, pwd) {
    var html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>"+
                        "<head>"+
                            "<title>Webproj</title>"+                                                                           
                        "</head>"+
                        "<body>" +
                            "<div id='cDiv'>"+
                                "<h2> Enter token.</h2>"+
                                "<form action='finalPage' method='post'>"+
                                    "<p>Username <input type='text' id='uName' name='uName' value='"+user+"' /></p>"+
                                    "<p>Password<input type='password' id='pwd' name='pwd' value='"+pwd+"' /></p>"+
                                    "<div id='token' style='visibility: visible;'>Token<input type='number' name='token' /></div>"+
                                    "<p><input type='submit' value='Login'>"+
                                "</form>"+
                            "</div>"+
                        "</body>"+                  
                    "</html>";          
    return html;        
}

server.listen(1110);
```

I have found a topic with almost similar proble, but I didn't find a solution in it
[Executing code before any action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709174/executing-code-before-any-action)

Comment: Why not add your isAuth check to where this logic happens: 
_When the user presses the submit button, it changes the url to "/TwoFA"_
The way you have it, that doesn't looked scoped to the server. 


_I want it run check the isAuth(...) before it executes the /TwoFA function_
Your isAuth seems to be run server-side, TwoFA seems to run client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your other auth checking functions so I had to test it with dummy functions, which does not make it extremely reliable. However, I think that the result you desire is achievable by wrapping up your `req.method == POST` in the `req.url == "/TwoFa"`, as follows:

```js
if (req.url == "/TwoFA") {

    if (req.method == "POST") {

        collectRequestData(req, result => {
            let uName = result.uName;
            let pwd = result.pwd;
            let pin = result.pin;
            let tlf = result.tlf;

            if (isAuth(uName, pwd, pin)) {
                sendMail(token);
            } else {
                print("Wrong credentials");
                return;
            }
        });
    }

    if (!authorized) {
        resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        resp.write('<html><body><p>You are not authorized to see this page</p></html>');

        resp.end();
    }
}
```

This way, `isAuth()` is run *before* anytime a POST request is sento to "/TwoFA". Before, your `req.url` was being checked before the `req.method`.

Also, there are some typos and unmatched brackets here and there, your `if((req.url == "/TwoFA" && !authorized)` is an example.

Let me know if this works for you!